# How to pass a variable into a regExp object in JavaScript and make it work

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a problem I can not solve. Let's say I have a variable that keeps the regExp pattern, that is to be provided by the user:

```
var pattern = this.state.regExpVal;
```

I also have a variable that keeps the value of textInput, meaning some piece of text, eg, postal codes.

var str = this.state.textAreaVal;

I create a new regExp object:

```
var myRegEx = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
```

And the result is not ok:(it seems that the flag search globally is not working and I can not figure out why);

```
var result = str.match(myRegEx);
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: What is the string and what is the regex you are trying?

Comment: Both string and regex are to be provided by the user. Let's say that var str='34-990' and pattern for regExp=\d{2}-\d{3}.

Answer (score 1):

```
let reg = new RegExp("super", 'g');
"SOsuperISsuper!".match(reg);
```

The result is an Array with 2 Elements ["super","super"] as expected.

I guess the problem lies within your `this` some `undefined` or  `null` values or in case-sense (try include 'i')

Edit:

```
let myObject = {
    state: {
     regExpVal: "super"
    }
}
let reg = new RegExp(myObject.state.regExpVal, 'g');
"SOsuperISsuper!".match(reg);
```

Edit 2:

```
let myObject = {
    state: {
     regExpVal: "super"
       }
   };
let pattern = myObject.state.regExpVal;
let reg = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
"SOsuperISsuper!".match(reg);
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know whether there is an option to put variables into the pattern.                                                                                      var pattern = this.state.regExpVal;
     var str = this.state.textAreaVal;
      var reg = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');-----here                                                         trying str.match(reg) is not working ok. Both pattern and str are strings.

Comment: I guess maybye the problem lays somewhere else, because I have been trying all combinations. Thank you for the support.

Comment: You can use variables, but if your value, who feeds the patter variable, is changing, you have to create a new RegEx Object.

Comment: insert a  debugger;  statement and inspect your variables at runtime. "this" is tricky for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would benefit you to provide a few concrete examples. It's difficult to help as well as would be possible without such. However, I can provide examples of how one constructs a regular expression from variables.

Let's assume your variable from which you wish to construct an "on-the-fly" regular expression matching pattern is

```
const someVar = 'LostInJavaScript';
```

Use of the `Regular Expression` constructor, as you seem to be using, is the necessary approach to take here. Inside the constructor, I tend to favor using ES2015-style string templates for the first argument passed it:

```
const regPattern = new RegExp(`${someVar}`, 'g');
// => /LostInJavaScript/g
```

Apply the relevant/appropriate `String` method (*e.g.*, [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)) passing it this dynamically created regular expression.

```
const strInput = 'RegularExpressionsHaveMeLostInJavaScript...',
      matchedSubStr = strInput.match(regPattern);
// => ["LostInJavaScript"]
```